# String must contain a specific character once

Tags: javascript, regex

When writing a regex I only know how to specify what is ALLOWED to be in a string, but I don't know how to specify what MUST be in it.

Let's say I need a regex that validates e.g. a sentence that contains exactly one `$` character anywhere.

```
"This $ should validate."
"This shouldn't validate."
"This $ should not $ validate either."
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remember that `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions, and so you'll need to refer to it using `\$` (escaping it with a backslash). There's one exception to this: in a character class, you don't need to escape it.

The special meaning it would normally have is "the end of the string"

What you really want is a regular expression which matches

- The begging of the string,
- Zero or more characters that *aren't* a dollar
- A dollar
- Zero or more characters that *aren't* a dollar
- The end of the string

And, the way you'd do that is

- `^`
- `[^$]*`
- `\$`
- `[^$]*`
- `$`

To explain the `[^$]` notation: the `^` means "not".

The final regular expression you'll want is `^[^$]*\$[^$]*$`. You can use `str.test()` to determine whether your string passes this condition.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[^$\n]*\$[^$\n]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PBzsRH/1

Answer (score 2):

Allow any number of any character other than `$` either side of the one allowed `$`:

```
isValid = /^[^$]*\$[^$]*$/.test(theString);
```

The `^` and `$` assert beginning and end, respectively; `[^$]` matches anything but `$`. `*` means "zero or more times". The `\$` in the middle is the one literal allowed `$`.

Live Example with your test strings:

```js
function test(theString) {
    var isValid = /^[^$]*\$[^$]*$/.test(theString);
    console.log(theString, "=>", isValid ? "valid" : "invalid");
}
test("This $ should validate.");
test("This shouldn't validate.");
test("This $ should not $ validate either.");
```